# XPath and negation searches

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following code sample in an `xmlns` root:

```
<ol class="stan">
    <li>Item one.</li>
    <li>
        <p>Paragraph one.</p>
        <p>Paragraph two.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <pre>Preformated one.</pre>
        <p>Paragraph one.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I would like to perform a different operation on the first item in `<li>` depending on the type of tag it resides in, or no tag, i.e. the first `<li>` in the sample.

---

EDIT:

My logic in pursuing the task turns out to be incorrect.

1. How do I query a `<li>` that has no descendants as in the first list item?

I tried negation:

```
@doc.xpath("//xmlns:ol[@class='stan']//xmlns:li/xmlns:*[1][not(p|pre)]")
```

That gives me the exact opposite for what I think I am asking for.

I think I am making the expression more complicated since I can't find the right solution.

---

UPDATE:

Navin Rawat has answered this one in the comments. The correct code would be:

```
@doc.xpath("//xmlns:ol[@class='stan']/xmlns:li[not(xmlns:*)]")
```

---

CORRECTION:

The correct question involves both an XPath search and a Nokogiri method.

Given the above `xhtml` code, how do I search for first descendant using `xpath`? And how do I use `xpath` in a conditional statement, e.g.:

```
@doc.xpath("//xmlns:ol[@class='stan']/xmlns:li").each do |e|
    if e.xpath("e has no descendants")
        perform task
    elsif e.xpath("e first descendant is <p>")
        perform second task
    elsif e.xpath("e first descendant is <pre>")
        perform third task
    end
end
```

I am not asking for complete code. Just the part in parenthesis in the above `Nokogiri` code.

Comment: Try to use xmlns:li[not(xmlns:*)]

Comment: Thanks @NavinRawat that answered part of the question. I made corrections as my logic in pursuing the problem was flawed.

Comment: Don't bother using `<del>` tags to mark up things you changed. We can look at the edit history if anything is confusing. Similarly, you don't have to put a chain of "EDIT:", "CORRECTION:" and similar tags unless they're really necessary. Keep your question clearly stated and provide the needed information up front and we can figure it out pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure XPath answer...

If you have the following XML :

```
<ol class="stan">
    <li>Item one.</li>
    <li>
        <p>Paragraph one.</p>
        <p>Paragraph two.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <pre>Preformated one.</pre>
        <p>Paragraph one.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And want to select  `<li>` that has no child element as in the first list item, use :

```
//ol/li[count(*)=0]
```

If you have namespaces problem, please give to whole XML (with the root element and namespaces declaration) so that we can help you dealing with it.

EDIT after our discussion, here is your final tested code :):

```
@doc.xpath("//xmlns:ol[@class='footnotes']/xmlns:li").each do |e|
  if e.xpath("count(*)=0")
    puts "No children"
  elsif e.xpath("count(*[1]/self::xmlns:p)=1")
    puts "First child is <p>"
  elsif e.xpath("count(*[1]/self::xmlns:pre)=1")
    puts "First child is <pre>"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition to child-less part of xpath search. I don't have namespace problems. I just can't figure how to use that xpath in a conditional statement in Nokogiri.

Comment: Thanks again, that addition I can figure easily. There is a reason I want the conditional statement. I didn't mention it because it would make the question more complicated and I might get the user distracted for lack of proper use of language. Does `@doc.xpath...` return a false/true value to be  used in an `if` statement, that would help answer the question after the queries you've posted in the update. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I have just edited the `ruby` code to make it as much as i can more clear or the conditions I am looking for which will return true/false for the conditional statement use.

Comment: I have figured out the first conditional: `if e.xpath("count(*)=0")`. Since I am drilling into the path to get that, can you suggest a way to drill down the path for the `p` path?

Comment: Are you looking for something like  `count(*[1]/self::p)=1` ? (Not sure to understand well the drill down you speak about)

Comment: I mean for the second and third conditional where I want `<li>` that its first child is `<p>` and `<li>` that its first child is `<pre>` respectively. I've been reading and trying all sorts of ways but no luck so far. Precisely I want an `xpath` form that returns true for: current-positionin-path's first child is `<p>` or `<pre>`. I have tried `[*[1]/self::xmlns:p]` but that didn't work.

Comment: in xpath 1.0, you have implicit conversion to a boolean value if needed. So the XPath expression should work. But you can try something like in my comment above :  `count(*[1]/self::p)=1` to get an actual boolean. But I don't understand your `xmlns:`. Can you provide the root element, ancestor of `ol`, that provide namespaces informations

Comment: xmlns is the root, the file is an xhtml5 that has xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml".

Comment: your xmlns:p is weird. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx) for a good picture on namespaces. If you want to avoid namespaces problem use this xpath : `[*[1]/self::*[local-name()='p']]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29544/discussion-between-ismail-and-vincent-biragnet)